# changing css stylesheets and saving chosen stylesheet to a database

Tags: c#, sql, css, database, stylesheet

I have two css stylesheets one called `blue.css` and one called `red.css`. Both contain code for changing the background of a button `blue.css` making the button blue and `red.css` making the button red.

I have a drop down list which contains the colours red and blue and the background of the button changes to the option chosen. But when the website is revisted the button returns to the default grey colour. I know I have to create an `SQL` database and somehow save the chosen value to the database so next time the site is run say for example: The default colour grey is shown and i choose red in the drop down list then i close the web page and then re open it and the background of the button is still red.

I know how to create tablea and edit them in `SQL` but not sure how to get it working with my code. I am coding in `c#`. If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT* I'm not allowed to use cookies for this

Answer (score 2):

No you don't really need a database as you can store the information (`blue.css` or `red.css`) in a cookie. The cookie is even necessary if the data gets stored in a DB, because you need to identify the user. Then upon each request you can check for that cookie (either server-side via C# or client-side via JavaScript) and insert the according stylesheet.

Comment: Cookies are your friend! Good god please don't use SQL and C# for this.

Comment: Hi there really sorry that I forgot to mention I'm not allowed to use cookies :(. Thats why I've chosen to use a database but if there is another alternative which is easier I'm all ears :)

Comment: If you're not allowed to use cookies, you have a big problem here, as you're trying to emulate a cookie behaviour through a DB. And in that case, you have to sort problems like storing a lot of secondary info, that could lead to an enormous DB, depending on the traffic of your page, or if the users of your page doesnt need to log in, how would you identify every user and store her/his color choice?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. We have a huge database so its fine. Each user is assigned to a company database and that entire company will have the same theme. I thought it would be quite a bit of secondary info I just cant get my head around how it will actually work :(

Comment: No worries guys came up with a solution. Ended up saving the style sheet as a session and saving that value into the users database works fine now :)